# How do i stream audio file with an image using ffmpeg to Telegram rtmp server

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, telegram, rtmp

I am trying to stream an audio file/radio but i want it to have a picture or video file to be viewed and not just audio. I do managed to stream audio and picture to Youtube rtmp server but for some reason not to Telegram. Someone knows how to do that?

Comment: please let me know the ffmpeg command that you use

Comment: For instance:
`ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -i "picture.jpg" -i "audiofile/radio" -c:a libmp3lame -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rmtp.server`

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, i needed to add this `-f image2` to the line and change the codec to aac. For example this is how it looks:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -f image2 -i imagefile -i audiofile/radio -c:v libx264 -vf scale=400:-2 -preset veryfast -b:v 2500k -maxrate 2500k -bufsize 5000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv rtmpserver
```